# Gradient of the Inverse Normal CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a stochastic variable modelled as $x \sim \mathbb{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and I am considering thresholds in $x$ based on the probability of reaching these values, e.g. find $x$ such that $p = P(X \geq x) = 0.8 \,/\,  0.9 \, / \, 0.95$ etc.

Naturally this requires looking at a CDF (i.e. $\Phi(x)$) - but since $x$ is a function of $p$, it is the inverse CDF that I am considering: $\Phi^{-1}(p)$ with $p \in [0,1]$. This is referred to as the probit function when $\mu = 0, \sigma = 1$., and characterises completely the value of $x$ for a given $p$.

Along with this, consider some payoff function e.g. $f(x,p) = x \cdot p - 3p$, and since $x(p) = \Phi^{-1}(p)$, the expected payoff depends wholly on $p$. I want to understand the gradient of this function. This sets up an optimisation problem in $p$ to maximise the payoff function.

Now, whilst $\Phi(x)$ has a well-known equation:
$$\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{ \frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}$$

And so presumably:

$$\frac{\partial{\Phi(x)}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}$$

I cannot find a similar 'known' result for:

$\Phi^{-1}(p)$ and $\frac{\partial{\Phi^{-1}(p)}}{\partial{p}}$

If there is not one, $\frac{\operatorname{d}f(x,p)}{\operatorname{dp}}$ cannot be solved analytically, but given that:

$$ x = \Phi(p)$$
$$ p = \Phi^{-1}(x)$$

can we solve the optimisation problem instead in $x$? So find the stationary point at $\frac{\operatorname{d}f(x,p)}{\operatorname{dx}} = 0$, and the simply recover the optimal probability with $\hat{p} = \Phi^{-1}(\hat{x})$?

Comment: The inverse of the normal distribution CDF does not have a closed form, but computers can calculate these as accurately as you want.  For a standard normal, $\Phi^{-1} (0.8) \approx 0.8416212$,  $\Phi^{-1} (0.9) \approx 1.281552$,  $\Phi^{-1} (0.95) \approx 1.644854$, $\Phi^{-1} (0.975) \approx 1.959964$, and the last of these is well known as $1.96$ since it is used in many two-tailed hypothesis tests and in constructing  confidence intervals

Comment: The derivative you want for $\frac{dx}{dp}$ is $\frac{1}{\phi(\Phi^{-1}(p))}$ where $\phi$ is the PDF. It's not a closed form, but it's as closed as $\Phi^{-1}$ was in the first place.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the question to be a bit clearer. I actually want df(x,p)/dp - but can perhaps use df(x,p)/dx as a proxy if that is differentiable analytically?